# Why does Subversion fail to flag a modified Microsoft Excel spreadsheet file?

Tags: excel, svn

I have encountered some behaviour I didn't expect from Subversion, and discovered this almost accidentally: A modified file is not being flagged as modified.

I have a unit test involving a Microsoft Excel spreadsheet as an input file. The unit test calculates a CRC checksum; my test started failing due to the checksum changing.

The test file is stored in SVN, and has MIME type "application/octet-stream", and is therefore considered as binary by SVN.

I get the same behaviour from TortoiseSVN and the SVN command line client, in this case both based on SVN 1.6: When the file is opened in Excel, the fact that it is open must be encoded in the file itself; SVN shows that the file is modified. However, when the file is closed again (without saving), it seems to return to its unmodified state: that is, `svn status` does not list the Excel file; `svn diff` produces no output anyway due to the data being binary.

The catch is that the file does not now binary compare with the file stored in the repository. (If a fresh copy is exported, it does not binary compare with the opened-and-closed copy.) The file is apparently unchanged from the user's point of view, so in a semantic sense, the SVN response is reasonable. But not syntactically; and SVN is essentially syntactic.

The part for which I can't find a reason is why SVN does not flag the file as modified. I can't imagine SVN has any special handling for Excel files (and in any case the MIME type is not specifically one associated with MS Excel); there is no SNV keyword property defined. Likewise, I can imagine Excel knows anything about the contents of the hidden .svn subdirectory in which the SVN working copy information is stored.

Do you have any clues as to what is going on here?

Thanks, Rob.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Excel always locks files on open, setting the timestamp to the current date. When you close without saving, Excel will revert the timestamp back. This causes SVN to ignore the file.

As for the changed contents, I'm not sure. Can you reproduce the problem?

Comment: Thanks. Yes the problem is reproducible. This sounds like a likely explanation; I'd pretty much said this in my comment to Wim's reply, but it's good to have it independently observed. I'll check this (at work, tomorrow).

Comment: Just to connfirm: that's exactly what's going on. When the Excel file is opened, the content of the file is changed (as can be seen with e.g. md5sum) and the modified time changes. When the file is closed without saving, the file content does not change, but does not revert to its original state either; and the modified time does revert to the value before opening.

Comment: Just found this: http://spreadsheetpage.com/index.php/oddity/who_last_opened_that_file/ it looks like Excel saves the name of the opener (and maybe more), even if you don't save. Weird.

Comment: @Marin excellent find, this is surely the problem.  The only ways I see how to fix this are to 1) Tell Excel to stop modifying files under the covers or 2) Change the timestamp when it does or 3) Have the SVN client force a checksum recalculation for *.xls files regardless of the timpstamp values.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to do any of those things, do you?

Answer (score 4):

Subversion assumes that the "last modification" time stamp is not lying. If the timestamp is unchanged, the content of the file is not checked for changes. I think all version control system do this, checking for local modifications would be unbearably slow otherwise.

**edit:** for the details of how SVN works in this regard, [questions.c](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/branches/1.6.x/subversion/libsvn_wc/questions.c) in the source of the SVN working copy library is a good start.

Comment: Just what I was about to suggest - check the timestamp :-) I've had a few weird problems where it wasn't being set properly that were remarkably similar to this one.

Comment: Again, a good suggestion. Thanks. I thought I'd seen the timestamp updated. I wonder if Excel changes the timestamp upon opening, but changes it back upon close-without-save. I'll check again (more carefully) later.

Comment: I just hit this exact problem, `hashcheck` would show a different checksum but TortoiseSVN would not report it.  Looked at the SVN checksum value and it remained the same.  Do you know of any client that has the ability to say something to the effect of *Always checksum *.xls files regardless of timestamp*?

Comment: @SiegeX: no, but you can force SVN to do a full compare by changing the timestamp yourself. It shouldn't be too hard to write a script that nudges the timestamp on every xls file in a given directory.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible the file is locked by excel while it is open and svn can't access it to see if it has changed or not?

Comment: I think MS applications usually indicate locking in a separate hidden file (something like `~file.doc`), but I think Excel is different. Locking is one clue, but I don't think that's the whole story, and I don't thing access is prevented. (I need to experiment more.)